# Problem with music pausing

Tags: samsung

I've recently been having problems with my samsung j3. At first I thought that my earbuds were broken because the music paused every time the plug moved but that isnt the problem.

Every time I move the ear plug-in the musc pauses and most of the time the phone plays the music out of the speaker instead of the earbud connection. What is the problem here? I constantly have to leave my phone still and move around the earbuds plug-in in order to get a good connection.

Comment: Sounds as though either a faulty connector or phone jack

Answer (score 3):

You said that when you plug in the earphones the music pauses and when you resume it starts playing on the phone speaker.
That is because the connection between your earphones and the headphone jack in your mobile isn't established.
The main reasons behind this is maybe there is some dirt in the headphone jack. You can remove it with an earbud.
In some other cases usually the headphone jack is damaged and needs to be replaced. I have this same issue and I didn't find any solution to this. So I bought a pair of bluetooth headphones.